# A Math Puzzle with a Pattern

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Inspired from a puzzle marathon, here is a math puzzle. There is a pattern with this set of numbers (not in the creation though). According to the pattern, what is the logical replacement for the question marks?

$$\begin{align}
3 & 5 & 1 & 6 & 8 & 2 \\
1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
\\
5 & 1 & 3 & 8 & 1 & 4\\
7 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 9\\
\\
6 & 7 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 1\\
? & ? & 5 & 3 & 8 & 2\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: What was the name of the puzzle marathon, by the way? Are they annual? Just curious is all :D

Comment: It's not annual... it's just a thread here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1666263

Comment: Oh, at the art of problem solving! Should have expected that. Thank you :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's:

> 34

because:

> read each $2\times2$ entry as a determinant (ad-bc), where:
>
> ```
>  a   b
>  c   d
> ```
>
> and we get
>
> ```
>  4  -3  2
>  3  -2  1
>  ?  -1  0
> ```
>
> So $?=2$, and $34$ is the first positive integer that fits, although I can't see any logic in the choice of numbers on the top - there are several that would do the same trick.

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Also, I didn't mean to choose any logical sequence of generating numbers... just a few examples :)